# Django admin super_user and normal user permissions

Tags: django, admin

I made a view to show all the `Transactions` `model` in the admin page. So basically i added a button in admin page which will redirect me to a custom html view with all `Transactions` .

my `views.py`

```
def pdfs(request, *args, **kwargs):
    transactions = Transaction.objects.all()
    template_path = 'report.html'
    context = {"transactions":transactions}
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='Application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="reportss.pdf'
    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(context)
    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=response)
    if pisa_status.err:
        return HttpResponse('we had some errors' + html )
    return response
```

`models.py`

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   rent_effective_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   income_period = models.CharField(max_length=11)
   group = models.OneToOneField(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

   def __str__(self):
    return str(self.chp_reference)
   
   @property    
   def print_pdf(self):
    if self.complete:
        view_link = reverse('pdfss')
        mark_safe_param = '<a href= {} target="_blank" >Print Report</a>'.format(view_link)
        return mark_safe(mark_safe_param)
    return 'Insufficient Info.'
```

and here is my `html` but i will keep it short

```
{% for transaction in transactions %}
    {% if transaction.complete %} 
            <th style="color:#3531FF">Report For Tenant ( {{ transaction.chp_reference }} )</span>        
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="9">CHP Reference</td>
            <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="3">{{transaction.chp_reference}}</td>
 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="9">Rent Effective From (dd/mm/yyyy)</td>
            <td class="tg-0pky" colspan="3">{{transaction.rent_effective_date}}</td>

        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="9">CRA Fortnightly Rates valid for 6 months from</td>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">{{transaction.cra_rate_from}}</td><hr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="9">Market Rent of the Property</td>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">{{transaction.property_market_rent}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="9">Number of Family Group(s)</td>
            <td class="tg-0lax" colspan="3">{{transaction.number_of_family_group}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{% if transaction.complete %}
<table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 714px">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 86px">
        <col style="width: 201px">
        <col style="width: 109px">
        <col style="width: 63px">
        <col style="width: 121px">
        <col style="width: 134px">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for f in transaction.family_groups.all %}
            <th style="text-align:left">Family No</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Income Type</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Rent %</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Weekly Income</th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><span ">Rent Component</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-4erg">{{f.name}}</td>
            <td >{% for m in f.family_members.all %}{{ m.num_of_family_members }}<br>{% endfor %}</td>
            <td >{% for m in f.family_members.all %} {{m.name}} <br> {% endfor %}</td>
            <td class="tg-4erg">{% for m in f.family_members.all %} {{m.effective_rent_percentage}} <br> {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td class="tg-4erg">{% for m in f.family_members.all %} {{m.income}} <br> {% endfor %}</td>
            <td class="tg-1qbe">{% for m in f.family_members.all %} {{m.income_component|stringformat:".2f"}} <br> {% endfor %}</td>
```

and finally i add these to `list_display =` in `Transaction`. And what im trying to do is I want only to show `Transation` objects to A group users. So a user in a group will only be able to `Print pdf` created by this group. Or even a user level. i want to know how to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def pdfs(request, *args, **kwargs):
   if request.user.is_superuser:
   transactions = Transaction.objects.all()
   else: transactions = 
   Transaction.objects.filter(user__groups=request.user.groups.first())
   template_path = 'report.html'
   context = {"transactions":transactions}
   response = HttpResponse(content_type='Application/pdf')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="reportss.pdf'
   template = get_template(template_path)
   html = template.render(context)
   pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=response)
   if pisa_status.err:
       return HttpResponse('we had some errors' + html )
   return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You could decorate your views with a `@permission_required("transaction.view")` decorator as [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator). You'd then assign the permission (that gets created automatically from the model) to a group and add users to that group, or give the permission directly to a user. Django's superuser status means the user has all permissions without having them explicitly granted. The decorator will always evaluate to True.